# Cinema 4d R13 .dae will not import into SceneKit

Tags: collada, scenekit, cinema-4d

I have a Cinema 4d R13 beating heart model that I would like to use in scene kit. The exported `.dae` file will not open in Xcode or in Preview on the Mac. Has anyone had problems importing animated cinema 4d r13 `.dae` files into SceneKit?

I'm very new to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know if Cinema4D exports to Collada 1.5 or 1.4 ? (SceneKit only supports 1.4). I believe there is a preference in Cinema4D R13 to specify 1.4

Comment: I will ask the animators to try that and report back. Thanks!

Comment: A simple cube exported to Collada 1.4 loaded properly (exported from Cinema4D R13 and R15). So, it seems that Collada 1.5 was the issue. Thanks! Now we need to get the animation to load and I understand that SceneKit does not support PLAs.

Comment: you can export in 1.4 and 1.5. I tried to use 1.5 and that did not work unfortunately :/ I'll try the 1.4 too. thanks @Toyos

Answer (score 2):

You can see from [their sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKitAnimations/Introduction/Intro.html) that the `.dae` files are exported using version `1.4.1` of Collada.

`<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">`

A static model is quite straightforward from there, but an animation is just impossible using Cinema 4D (or at least I didn't find a way).
The infuriating thing is that their own animation model was created on... a PC, using 3ds Max.

`<authoring_tool>OpenCOLLADA for 3ds Max;  Version: 1.2.5;  Revision: 673;  Platform: Win32;  Configuration: Release Max2010</authoring_tool>`

If anyone finds a way to export C4D animations to .dae that can be previewed on Mac and used in SceneKit, I'm interested !

Answer (score 1):

For now you seem to only be able to import Collada files with a version up to 1.4.1.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Just curious, because I haven't been able to find anything from Apple.